# External jpa connection - Spring Boot

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an application with two databases.

The main one of Mongo and a connection to one of Postgres.

In production the connection of postgres that is in an external server (Mongo is in the same machine).

As I deploy it if it connects me correctly to the database of Postgres, but when it happens a little time loses the connection and no longer recovers it.

What parameters should I play in order to not close the connection?

```
spring:
devtools:
    restart:
        enabled: false
    livereload:
        enabled: false
data:
    mongodb:
        uri: mongodb://xxxxx:27017
        database: xxx
datasources:    
    elser:
        driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
        url: jdbc:postgresql://222.21.224.337:5432/xxx
        username: username
        password: password
mail:
    host: localhost
    port: 25
    username:
    password:
thymeleaf:
    cache: true
jpa:
    show-sql: true
    database-platform: io.github.jhipster.domain.util.FixedPostgreSQL82Dialect
    database: POSTGRESQL
    properties:
        hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: true
        hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: false
        hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
        hibernate.generate_statistics: true
        hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect
```

Comment: Spring Boot tries to use a connection pool when it detects a non in-memory database. The default pool [as explained here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connect-to-production-database) is that provided by Tomcat. So, unless you are supplying your own connection pool, setting `spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true` will force Tomcat to test connection before handing it your code and if the connection is invalid, replace it. However, note that most pools are notorious for not recovering from failures correctly.

Answer (score 0):

manish: It would be like this?

```
data:
    mongodb:
        uri: mongodb://srv-xxx:27017
        database: xxx
datasources:    
    elser:
        driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
        url: jdbc:postgresql://185.25.114.57:5432/XXX
        username: XXXX
        password: XXXX
    tomcat:
        test-on-borrow:true
```